# Convert two subversion repos on googlecode to a single git repo on github

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn, google-code

(1) How do I convert two subversion repos, one of which is an external of the other to a single git repo on github?  I want the history to be interleaved so that the gitk output makes sense!

(2) Why would I want to use svnadmin dump instead of just `git clone`ing them and then moving them?

(3) How can I test my new repository to see that it matches the old pair of repositories?

For the sake of answering the questions, suppose the two subversion repositories are at http://acl2-devel.googlecode.com/svn and http://acl2-books.googlecode.com/svn, and that both repositories were setup with the standard svn layout (trunk, branches, tags).  Also, assume that I want a clean break and want a fresh start for branches and tags.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Here is the meta-level discussion of what I did to combine the two repos into a single git repo.

- Dump both subversion repositories using svnsync and svnadmin
- Create a new svn repository with the books repo mounted in a books
  subdirectory
- Remove all branches and tags from the svn repository (but leaving
  their history)
- Convert the svn repo to git, canonicalizing emails to match github
  account email addresses
- Remove all references to branches and tags in the history using "bfg"
- "Rewrite" the git history to accommodate the move from an internal server
  many years ago, the moving of the ACL2 system trunk up to root, and
  the moving of the books up a level
- Create a new repo and "cherry-pick" the 4000+ commits in order of
  timestamp to create a nicely ordered history
- Pushed the resulting repo to github

The script that implements the above is long and available at:
    https://github.com/ragerdl/svn-to-git/blob/master/convert-acl2-books-svn-and-acl2-devel-svn-to-git.sh

(2) Why not use git svn clone on both repositories and then merge them?

Because, when I got to the cherry-pick step, there were a good number of conflicts.  Performing it in this order avoided those conflicts.

(3) You can test your repository by making sure that, for every extension you care about, the count of each extension is the same in both repositories.  You can also perform a diff.  See https://github.com/ragerdl/svn-to-git/blob/master/quality-assurance.sh for a script that performs those actions.

I realize that copy+pasting code would be good, but there is so much, and this is my first cut.  If someone else would like to clean up the script I wrote and paste it in here, it would be appreciated.  I wouldn't consider this a real value-add to society, except I spent many hours reading others' posts, and I couldn't find an answer to this question.  Thus, I think this answer should go somewhere easily found by search engines.